# How to store fragment being popped by Fragment Manager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am going back to the last fragment onclick of an application back button as follows:

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
                fm.popBackStack();
            }
        }
```

How can I get access to the fragment being popped from the stack and store it in a variable?

Comment: If you pop a Fragment it is "gone". What do you want to achieve with such mechanics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add the transaction to backstack by

```
   fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(str_transaction_name);
```

Then you will be able to find the fragment by TAG:

```
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
   // Get the last transaction on the stack
   FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry=fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()-1);
   String str = backEntry.getName();
   Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(str);
```

Comment: @using tags when adding fragments is recommended since it would be easier to access that fragment from the `FragmentManager`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
```

to go to the previous fragment (which is what you want to do if I understand your question correctly)

For more information about how to use this check the Android documentation here [FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStackImmediate())